# Two different outputs

Tags: java

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with  and , the first 10 terms will be:

```
1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,...
```

And here we should find the even numbers in Fibonacci series and add them to the sum

And the code :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Abhi {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    int[] n = new int[t];

    int i,j;
    long sum;
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        n[a0] = in.nextInt();            
    }
    //int an = n.length;
    int[] nn = new int[1000];
    nn[0]=1;
    nn[1]=2;
    for(i = 0 ; i<t;i++){
        sum = 2;
        for(j= 2;j<n[i];j++){                
            nn[j] = nn[j-2] + nn[j-1];
                if(nn[j]%2==0 && nn[j]<n[i])
                    {
                    sum += nn[j];
                 //System.out.println(sum);   
                 //the above line shows correct output 
                }
            }            
        System.out.println(sum);//this is printing different output
    }}}
```

Sample input :

```
1
100
```

Sample output :

```
44
```

Comment: Your code and your question is unclear. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks to explain what is the fibonnaci sequence but I don't see any question here ... or any problem. PS : The sequence start like `1, 1, 2` or you should set `sum = 3` and not 2

Comment: What would be the correct output and why?

Answer (score 1):

Here problem in not with the outer System.out.println(sum); as you mentioned. It is because of int range.

Max value of int is 2 147 483 647 and in Fibonacci series 2 971 215 073 is in 47th position and as it exceeds the int range, it giving the results in unexpected manner.

In your code array nn holding  -1323752223 instead of 2971215073 which is actually causing the issue.

To resolve this issue use BigInteger as below

```
    BigInteger sum;
    BigInteger[] nn = new BigInteger[1000];
    nn[0] = new BigInteger("1");
    nn[1] = new BigInteger("2");
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        sum = new BigInteger("2");
        for (j = 2; j < n[i]; j++) {
            nn[j] = nn[j - 2].add(nn[j - 1]);
            if (nn[j].mod(new BigInteger("2")).equals(new BigInteger("0")) && 
                nn[j].compareTo(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(n[i])))<0) {
                sum = sum.add(nn[j]);
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Comment: @Thrasher He is using long for sum not for array nn and nn array holds the Fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int No = sc.nextInt();

        int fNo1 = 1;
        int fNo2 = 1;
        int fNo3 = fNo1 + fNo2;
        int sumofEvenNo = 0;
        int i;
        while( fNo3 < No)
        {
            if(fNo3 % 2 == 0)
                sumofEvenNo += fNo3;
            fNo1 = fNo2;
            fNo2 = fNo3;
            fNo3 = fNo1 + fNo2;
        }

        System.out.println("Sum of all even nos = "+sumofEvenNo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, this is way easier but you doesn't answer the problem since there is no problem for the moment ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), your code will be more clear and easy to debug. I'm using a [static method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to get the sum also.

1. Ask how many times the sum will be calculated.
2. Get the index and calculate the sum.
3. Print.

### Class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Abhi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println ( "This program will calculate the even sum of given fibonacci series index ( index starts at 1) " );
        System.out.println ( "Please enter how many times do you want to calculate the sum: " );
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int iterationTimes = scan.nextInt() ;

        for (; iterationTimes > 0; iterationTimes-- )
        {
            System.out.println ( "Please, enter the index on fibonacci: " );
            System.out.println ( "Even sum: " + getEvenSum( scan.nextInt() ) );
        }

    }

    private static long getEvenSum( int index)
    {
        if ( index <= 2 )
        {
            return 0;
        }

        long n1=1, n2=1, n3, sum = 0;   

        for(int i = 2; i < index; i++) 
        {    
            n3=n1+n2;
            if ( n3 % 2 == 0)
            {
                sum += n3;
            }
            n1=n2;    
            n2=n3;    
        }  

        return sum;

    }


}
```

### I/O Example:

```
This program will calculate the even sum of given fibbonacci series index ( index starts at 1 )
Please enter how many times do you want to calculate the sum: 
3
Please, enter the index on fibbonacci: 
3
Even sum: 2
Please, enter the index on fibbonacci: 
6
Even sum: 10
Please, enter the index on fibbonacci: 
12
Even sum: 188
```

**Note:** Fibbonaci: 1, 1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: You should highlight your changes. Since I still see `int sum` I doubt this will works for a "long" time